# vaadin setItemCaptionPropertyId more then one caption in combobox

Tags: java, vaadin

I using an BeanItemContainer to fill a combobox, like this :

```
//filling the combobox with UserDTO's by BeanContainer
    BeanItemContainer<SubCategoryDTO> beanContainer = new BeanItemContainer<SubCategoryDTO>(
            SubCategoryDTO.class);
    ArrayList<SubCategoryDTO> subcategorys = qpc.getSubcategorys();
    beanContainer.addAll(subcategorys);
    cmbCategory.setContainerDataSource(beanContainer);
    cmbCategory.setItemCaptionMode(ItemCaptionMode.ID);
    cmbCategory.setImmediate(true);
    cmbCategory.setNewItemsAllowed(false);
    cmbCategory.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    cmbCategory.setItemCaptionPropertyId("name");
```

The DTO has following  fields :

```
public class SubCategoryDTO  extends Observable implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int subCategoryId;
private String name;
private CategoryDTO category;
...
```

I would like to let the ItemCaption of the combobox show both the name and the category name (DTO also has a name field), so I would get something like : *categoryName subCategoryName*

Is there a way to do so? Any suggestion would be appreciated!  Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the item caption on the combobox itself using `ItemCaptionMode.EXPLICIT` and `combo.setItemCaption(id, caption)` or add a read only property to your bean:

```
public class SubCategoryDTO {

  private String name;
  private CategoryDTO parent;

  public String getCaption() {
    return parent.getName() + " " + name;
  }

}
```

and use `ItemCaptionMode.PROPERTY` and `combo.setItemCaptionPropertyId("caption")`. Similarly, you can put the captioning logic inside the overridden `toString()` and use `ItemCaptionMode.ITEM`

Comment: combo.setItemCaptionPropertyId("caption") did the trick.  thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide an example on how to override `toString()` and which one and where to override? I'd like to use this technique in combination with `ItemCaptionMode.ITEM` but I don't see how to do it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way (there may be easier ways). You can iterate over the items in the ComboBox and set an item caption.

Like this:

```
for(Object subCatDTO : cbmCategory.getItemIds()){
    SubCategoryDTO subCategoryDTO = (SubCategoryDTO) subCatDTO;
    cbmCategory.setItemCatption(subCatDTO, subCategoryDTO.getName + " " + subCategoryDTO.getCategory().getName());
}
```

I think that may solve your problem.
For more information: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/1394968